# Rather than "ought to be true = is true" being impossible, might it not just be a trivial stage of moral representation?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, category-theory, deontic-logic

I just finished reading [Eugenia Cheng's essay on moral phraseology in mathematics](https://eugeniacheng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cheng-morality.pdf), and so I want to go over something she says on pg. 20:

> A recent lecturer of Part III Category Theory declared that in Category Theory “Everything
> that ought to be true is true”. She (or he) was rewarded by one student feedback complaining that the whole subject was therefore trivial. However, the point is not triviality but *completeness*.

Cheng's analysis of use of words like "ought" and "moral" is not such as applies to behavior normally so-called. If belief can be construed as (abstract) behavior, her usage might be somewhat closer to the norm; she does go a little bit back and forth about how far removed her (and the mathematical community's) usage is from the non-mathematical case, and her final paragraph reads:

> We encourage children to ask the question “Why?” but only up to a point, because beyond that point we might not understand it ourselves. So we stifle their moralistic tendencies to match our own. Perhaps if we bring out the moral aspects of mathematics earlier on, we won’t end up with so many people lost in the mathematical wilderness.

Now, Ersnt Mally, who tried his hand at deontic logic but in such a way that he ended up with the seemingly dire conclusion that everything that is true, ought to be true, is so faulted for having concluded thus. Given some other despicable factoids pertaining to said fellow, I wouldn't much be minded to try to rehabilitate such an awful thesis at all, except I wonder: can we relate back from what Cheng said, to Mally's "error," and instead say that there is a stage in moral representation where "ought to be true" and "is true" do collapse into each other, **but this is in terms of a trivial stage/initial object in a category of such representations?** Or, then, is this even the implication of Cheng's reference, up until her own remark about moral completeness?

Comment: You should warn the users that Cheng's use of "morally" is highly deviant and has little to do with what it usually means. It is what some mathematicians mean when they call a result "morally true" or "ought to be true", i.e. in agreement with the intuitive "gist" of things considered or something to this effect. And "moral completeness" means that everything "morally true" is provably true. What "ought to be false", but is provably true, would sometimes be called "pathological". If by "trivial stage" you mean something like representing a theory in simple broadest strokes that might be it.

Comment: Perhaps ethics could be said to be a better name here for CT's thesis since the so called completeness from the intended 'ought' to the provable 'is' is meant to convince a whole community intersubjectively while morality is only applied to an individual at least regarding their intricate technical difference philosophically. The seemingly magic completeness collapse of statements here is always trivial in terms of the internal logic of their said category not because of any stage or initial object but since the troublesome incompleteness is already buried in the external foundation...

Comment: I see it a bit different. Mathematicians have the pleasure of constructing their own foundations, in order to create a framework where what they think "ought to be true" is actually true. Mostly everyone agrees the Peano Axioms are  a moral represenation of Natural Numbers, and so mostly everyones frameoworks construct the Naturals to adhere to Peano. Mathematicians who think AC ought not be true, have the freedom to work in ZF + ¬AC, and so what they believe ought not be true, actually isn't true. If a mathematician believes infinite sets ought not be true, they can work with finite sets and

Comment: do number theory. If they believe infinities ought exist, they'll add in an inductive set and play in a landscape with  infinite cardinals. Everything that ought to be true is true, because as Mathematicians, we get to build our own playgrounds. And, if something that ought to be true isn't true- then we just have to build another one.

Comment: In that context, the point would be that moral completeness could be a way to push math forward. If something ought to be true, but isn't in one domain, perhaps it is true in another... such as in Euclidean/Non-Euclidean geometry. And so for mathematical completeness- we want a field to contain "everything that ought to be true" because otherwise we need to work in a different domain, which does have whatever principle should be true, when it becomes relevent. Ultimate mathematical completeness ( morally) would contain all "ought to be true" facts, and would be a foundation for all mathematics