# Characterizing Mally's infamous theoretical outcomes as degenerate cases of moral representation

Tags: deontic-logic

The gist of those outcomes is a collapse of "is" and "ought" into each other, [e.g.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mally-deontic/#SurpCons):

[image]

(Apologies for the cutoff.) Is it safe to say that what Mally "discovered" was not, of course, a set of practicable nontrivial factoids of deontic logic, but [*degenerate*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Degenerate.html) stages of moral representation? And this degeneracy instead of [triviality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104355/rather-than-ought-to-be-true-is-true-being-impossible-might-it-not-just-be), then?

Comment: Who is Mally? Not familiar with this name.

Comment: @Olivier5 Ernst Mally was a pioneer in deontic logic, who came to bizarre and unfortunate conclusions in this domain of discourse, and was either a Nazi or Nazi sympathizer (eventually), but who for some reason is used as the namesake of Edward Zalta's metaphysics research lab online: https://mally.stanford.edu/ And Zalta is one of those heading up the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

Comment: Thanks! Will look him up.